# IIS 404 reply when requesting services locally

Tags: iis

Recently we switched from self-signed certificates to certificates from Let's Encrypt. We used a Windows ACME client (required by Let's Encrypt) to validate our hostname. We had to fill in the "Host Name" field in the https Binding properties page. After the process was succesful and we got the certificate, the web-site is functioning properly from the Internet but it gives a 404 response when we request things locally. If we delete the Host Name property the site functions as expected both locally and from the Internet. We would have the name removed but we set the ACME tool to auto-renew the certificate every three months. Is there a way to have the site both serve loally and leave the Host Name property intact?

Comment: "it gives a 404 response when we request things locally", then what URL gives you 404? Even locally you should use `https://domain-name` to access the site. More details, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi The URL we use locally is `https://server-ip`. We cannot use the domain name since all the internal network + the web-server operate on the same gateway.

Comment: Can you describe in detail how to configure the host name in IIS? You can show the relevant configuration in the applicationhost.config file. In addition, you can check the 404 [sub-status code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code#4xx---client-error) and use failed request tracing to check the problem.

Comment: A site binding with host name won't serve `https://server-ip`. You probably should modify hosts file on this server to map the domain name to 127.0.0.1, which can allow `https://domain-name` to work there.